# Why is logging into the seed so slow?

Tags: seed, wallet, android-wallet

Why does it sometimes need such a long time to log into the light wallet? 
Is it depending on how many transactions are already done inside the seed or is it depending on when was the last snapshot? Or is it a development problem that will be fixed in the future?

Comment: I think it depends on how many addresses you have in your wallet. All their balances get checked when you log in.

Comment: That could be possible. Will this get faster after a snapshot? If not I guess I should sometimes change the seed... But this would be a drawback from IOTA I guess. Because if a maschine does thousand of transactions ot is normal to have many addresses in the seed...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It has been observed that the more addresses in your wallet, the longer it takes for your computer to retrieve all associated addresses from the Tangle.

The new wallet should remedy this -- it will be stateful, and store your previous addresses locally, so you don't have to re-retrieve them every single time you log in.